# How to script tables in SSMS that contain non-unicode text

Tags: sql-server, scripting, ssms, non-unicode

I'm working with some tables in SQL Server that store text using 8-bit characters rather than unicode -- varchar rather than nvarchar. A certain amount of the text contains characters with values outside the ASCII range, for example curly quotes, em-dashes, and international characters such as ñ. Presumably this works because all our PCs and servers use the same code page.

However, when I use the Task > Generate Scripts scripting tool in SSMS to script such a table, the resulting script translates the special characters in such a way that if I use the script to reconstruct the table, the special characters are corrupted. For example "cañon" becomes "ca±on." I can see this in the INSERT statements that the script contains, where "cañon" from the database appears as "ca±on" in the INSERT statement.

In SSMS, how do I script a table that contains varchar data outside the ASCII range so that round-tripping will work?

Comment: In the Script Wizard's Output Option, are you saving as Unicode text, or ANSI text?

Comment: That's the answer. It defaults to Unicode, but I needed ANSI.

Answer (score 0):

In the Script Wizard's Output Option, you need to save as ANSI text, if you want to script extended ASCII data in CHAR and VARCHAR fields correctly.